# Remove unneccessary information from a link?

Tags: java, string

So I have a site where a user enters a link (which may or may not be from amazon). There's a problem with amazon links though since they add quite a lot of unneccessary information to the URL.

For example:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Xbox-360-Console-Wireless-Controller/dp/B00BM2LKHW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1394554640&sr=8-1&keywords=xbox+360

When I just need the following:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Xbox-360-Console-Wireless-Controller/dp/B00BM2LKHW

What's the best way to go about this?

Would it be like this:

```
   if (link.contains("amazon") {
         link = ....... //should i use the / as a marker? 
   }
```

Just a bit worried a user will enter it without the http:// and then it'll mess it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
link = link.substring(0, link.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: looks quite good to me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you: don't go in this direction. I'm sure there are a billion websites which use looooong URL's; are you going to handle each case? Just make sure your DB column is reasonably sized and allow everything in this range. Consider using a Regular Expression to validate if it's actually a URL.

Comment: I need to though, since I'm sending the link to an API which can't handle the full Amazon link unfortunately.